# Changing the prompt when ssh to another box

Tags: ssh, prompt, computing-environment

I want to be able to set a custom prompt (to help with automating jobs, the prompt should be something I can reliably detect).  I found I am able to set the prompt remotely, like this:

```
wim@wim-acer:~$ ssh guest@192.168.1.124 -i ~/.ssh/guest_nopassphrase 
~ # echo $PS1
\w \$
~ # PS1='Setting a custom prompt \w \$ '
Setting a custom prompt ~ # exit
Connection to 192.168.1.124 closed.
```

Is there a way to do it in one shot in the first place, by using a different ssh command?  The suggestion I tried in the answer of a related question didn't work for me:

```
wim@wim-acer:~$ ssh guest@192.168.1.124 -i ~/.ssh/guest_nopassphrase -t "PS1='Sending a custom prompt \w \$ '; exec sh"
~ # set
HOME='/var/tmp'
IFS='   
'
LOGNAME='guest'
PATH='/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin'
PPID='1039'
PS1='\w \$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
TERM='xterm'
USER='guest'
```

Comment: Not even if you add `export ` just in front of `PS1=`?

Comment: ah, your suggestion worked :)  if you add it as an answer, i can accept it tomorrow.

Comment: I just have it changed in my .bashrc file so I know what I'm on at a glance by what info is shown.

Comment: @Rob do you mean the .bashrc file on the remote machine?  if so, that is not an option for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ ssh ::1 -t "export PS1='Sending a custom prompt \w \$ '; exec sh"
Password: 
Sending a custom prompt ~ $ exit
Connection to ::1 closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider editing the `.bashrc` file on the remote host?

A simple:

```
export PS1='Setting a custom prompt \w \$ '
```

at the end of `~/.bashrc` on the remote host will make sure the prompt is changed each time you log in.  It will obviously affect any other users of the account too.

Comment: Thanks, I considered it - but I need to do it on hundreds of dumb boxes, so it is preferably to be able to send it on the fly rather than set it up on each one.